British 00's Crime-Reality TV Show, Similar to "Hunted"
After watching an advert for Hunted the other day, I know the format has been done before in the UK, but not as brutal. I remember watching it with my parents, so that dates it either very late 90s or early 00s - anything from 1999 to 2003.
My memory is pretty hazy on some aspects, but it involved members of (I believe) the public split into two. One was a "team" of investigators whose job it was to track down the other members, who may or may not have been in a team.
The show was shot in the style of a manhunt, with handheld cameras (like old-style HandyCams, I believe this was pre-GoPro) given to the hunted people, though there were also standard "crewed" camera angles used.
I think the detectives were given control of some ground-level "police" but were otherwise confined to an "incident room" style studio.
One aspect of the show that I am cast-iron certain of is that it was filmed in and around Essex, one episode involved a person getting stuck on an island that was only accessible with the tide (now known as Osea Island) and one other (possibly the same) episode involved an old hotel.
Each episode ended with an attempted capture, and if successful the captured person would walk through the "incident room" doors - which I think were metal.
Discounted shows so far:

Wanted (no incident room, and UK-wide)

